# Assign unique id each time two fields/columns are an exact match

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery, combinations

Big Query:

I'm looking to assign a 'unique combination id' if a person and date are an exact match. So for each specific time a 'person_id' and a specific datetime are the same, they are assigned a number overall (time will always be 00:00:00 but just has to be there for records). This will be a unique number overall, not for a count for each individual. Hope that makes sense.

Desired result below. So you'll see row 1 and 5 are the same unique combination, so have the same unique_combination_id.

| person_id | Datetime | unique combination_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2016-04-01T00:00:00 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2016-05-04T00:00:00 | 2 |
| 9102 | 2018-05-17T00:00:00 | 3 |
| 5678 | 2019-09-01T00:00:00 | 4 |
| 1234 | 2016-04-01T00:00:00 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DENSE_RANK()` should do the trick:

```
SELECT *, 
   DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER by person_id, datetime) as unique_combination_id
FROM tbl;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=15fa06610f48749d48b31f38e4ec9802)

Comment: Thank you so much - that' s perfect and works - I assume I could also include multiple datetime columns there if necessary.

Comment: Yes you can, if you are trying to add those `datetime` columns to assign `unique id`. Check that out the DEMO link before implementing.